# ESLint for React: is there a rule to detect props that need a useMemo?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, react-props, memoization

With react, in the JSX code returned by a functional component I can have:

MyComponent.jsx

```
<MySubComponent props1={{a: 0, b:1}}/>
OR
<MySubComponent props2={["toto", "tata"]}/>
```

Where my sub component is exported with memoization:

MySubComponent.jsx

```
export default React.memo(MySubComponent)
```

However **this breaks memoization**, because props with the format **{{...}}** or **{[...]}** will instanciate a new object/array each time (same value, but different memory address), thus props shallow-compare by React.memo sees it different.

**Is there any ESLint/JSLint rule to detect those kinds of props ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use useMemo to memoize the object or array and pass it as props to MySubComponent like this:

```
const obj = React.useMemo(() => ({a: 0, b:1}), []);

<MySubComponent props1={obj}/>
```

In SubComponent.jsx

```
export default React.memo(MySubComponent);
```

This only works for simple objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately this is not my case: it is a complex project with many developers. So I want ESLint to warn all the developers when a "useMemo" is better to avoid useless renderings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the issue, you don't need eslint to identify it for you unless this is a repeating pattern. It seems that you're already past discovery stage.

What I would recommend is to one of two options:

1. Override the the second parameter of `React.memo(Component, isEqual)` with a custom function in which you can compare the input array or object by value, so the changing prop reference becomes irrelevant so long as the content remains the same. However, if you're extensively re-rendering this component this might become an overhead.
2. Your other option is to define the array and object outside of your component and keep passing them with modified content but keeping the reference the same.